# angular click used with a variable

Tags: angular

I try to call `(click)` event in angular by passing a variable, but nothing happen

```
<a (click)="action">
  Login
</a>
```

And in my .ts file

```
action = 'login()';

login() {
  console.log('login !');
}
```

Is there a way to use `(click)` with a variable and not a static function name ?

Comment: why pass the variable as the function name in the event? instead, you can pass the variable as a parameter in function and do whatever you want to do, isn't it?

Comment: or check my answer as an alternate.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

## First Method -

You can pass varibale as method name using bracket notation like this-

```
<a (click)="this[action]()">
  Login
</a>
```

## [Working example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-cfmppt?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html)

## Second Method -

`(click)` event always expects `functionName()` as it's value.

In your scenario you can add dynamic `eventListner` to listen to your function using `@viewChild` like this -

```
<a #myEvent (click)="action">
  Login
</a>

@ViewChild('myEvent') myEvent: ElementRef;

  ngAfterViewInit() {
  (this.myEvent.nativeElement as HTMLElement).addEventListener('click', this.login.bind(this));

  // Here you can bind to any method 
}

  login() {
    console.log('login !');
  }
```

## [Working example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-yq9zbp?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)

Answer (score 4):

You do not pass a vaiable.

`(click)` is the event. `"login()"` is the method.

To pass a variable to a function:

```
(click)="login(args)"
```

Comment: thx for your aswer, but I don't want to pass a static function name in the `(click)`event

Comment: We can pass a variable as method name, you can check my answer here https://stackoverflow.com/a/50249916/5043867

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible because (click) expects function to be passed, the best you can do is this:

```
<a (click)="action()">
    Login
</a>
```

you need to CALL that 'action' variable that you set with function! 
And you cannot set action variable with string like you did! You must do it like this:

```
action = login();
```

not like this:

```
action = 'login()'
```

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

you can probably pass a function variable if you want it to be dynamic:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-admin',
  templateUrl: './admin.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./admin.component.css']
})
export class AdminComponent implements OnInit {

  clickHandler: any;

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.clickHandler = this.funcA;
  }

  private funcA() {
    console.log('call function A');
    this.clickHandler = this.funcB;
  }

  private funcB() {
    console.log('call function B');
    this.clickHandler = this.funcA;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This piece of code is working for me! You can try by your side!

component.ts
..

```
//new method:
callAction(actionName: string) {
 return this[actionName]();
}

//example:
close() {
  this.dialogRef.close();
}
```

component.html

```
<button (click)="callAction(action.method)" >
  {{ action.text }}
</button>
```

Answer (score -3):

It is as simple as yours
HTML:

```
<a (click)="login()">
  Login
</a>
```

TS:

```
login() {
  console.log('login !');
}
```

This will work for sure!

Comment: thx for your aswer, but I don't want to pass a static function name in the `(click)`event

Comment: click is an event and it should not be accommodated with a variable. You can have an expression there like (click)="action = 'login !'" but not with a variable. Also in your ts you had added an action login() as a string, which wont work.